# SslStream accept certificate?

Tags: c#, ssl, ftp

I made a simple ftp client in C# which does what I need (connect to a ftp, optionally using a proxy), but I want to be able to use AUTH SSL also.

So instead of NetworkStream I looked at SslStream and hoped it would be a fairly easy substitute.

However I seem to have a lot of problems when handshaking with my (glftpd, selfsigned openssl cert) ftp. Here's a code snippit:

```
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.0.2", 1337);
    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
                client.GetStream(),
                false,
                new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
                null
                );
        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("192.168.0.2"); // or "glftpd", neither worked.
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
            client.Close();
            return;
        }
```

I break on AuthenticateAsClient with IOException: "The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.".
I don't break in ValidateServerCertificate (never reached).

I find it hard to debug this error as I can set the TcpClient port to 1208219421 and still recieve the same error (so I don't even know if it fails to talk to a ssl port).

The code (among 3-4 different C# ssl guides I looked at) above is modified from [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx)

I've tried both sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(..., ..., SslProtocols.Tls, false) and sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(..., ..., SslProtocols.Ssl3, false) Ssl2 and Default, and I know for a fact that TLS works with my glftpd install.

If I had to guess I'd think it has something to do with machinename/certname, but I've tried the certname (which is "glftpd"), so right now I'm clueless as to why I get failed handshake.

Also it should be noted that the cert is self-signed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

- Chuck

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the port number?  Is that the problem?

EDIT 1

http://en.wikipedia.org/wki/FTPS

Perhaps your server is not in "Implicit" mode?  Should it be?

You probably want Explicit mode support in your product too/instead.

EDIT 2

(Apologies, I can't comment yet, not enough reps so I am making edits instead.  :-) )

If support for both explicit and implicit in your live code are not required, I often like to run TCP servers on two ports simultaneously if possible, one for implicit SSL and one for explicit/non-SSL.  Your server software may or may not support this.

EDIT 3

Depends whether you control the servers / how standards compliant you want to be!

Implicit mode will be regarded as slightly less standardsy but OTOH its less work.

EDIT 4

It may be better protection against denial-of-service issues to use Explicit rather than Implicit but I am not sure, I'd have to study the protocol.  My experience is with XMPP.

EDIT 5

Plus the plain text startup of explicit mode may make some corporate legal departments a little bit more relaxed about legal issues of any unauthorised access than with something that starts off doing TLS gibberish on the wire straightaway.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so. The port should be correct. 1337 is what I can connect to with non-SSL and with AUTH SSL in various ftp clients, but thanks for your reply.

Comment: You're right, implicit is not supported. So that could be it. What I want is either AUTH SSL or just TLS will do fine (if that's less work?)

Comment: My objective is simply to connect (TCP) to an IP. Then be able to send "AUTH TSL" (or "AUTH SSL") and accept the certificate no matter what, and then have a secure connection to that IP.

Comment: Relying on DNS alone not good - the DNS may be subject to man-in-the-middle attacks.  Do a risk assessment and probably try to avoid .  Also if you start using certificates, validate the results of each TLS handshake.  The negotiated protocol should be a recognised strong one (TLS libraries generally can negotiate connections from a suite of bundled protocols) and check the certificate fingerprint.  Ideally disable weak protocols in your TLS software.

Comment: I appreciate your security concern, but I need to at least say yes/no to accepting the cert, and by saying yes, it would accept no matter what.

Comment: ... Assuming the protocol negotiated uses a certificate that can be said yes/no to.  We're pretty much on the same page I feel.

Comment: Yes. But of course if SslStream doesn't allow you to accept a certificate that's selfsigned, then I think my project is better left alone, hehe.

Comment: Ok, port is right, but certificate is just not cooporating. Grrrr. "The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format." WHAT THE...

Can anybody tell me if there're some debug tools I can use to identify the problem? I tried raw'ing to the server on port 1337 (which the ssl is set to)  with no luck. Tried ssh'ing to it, no luck

Comment: Get some Unix tools for Windows and the OpenSSL toolkit?  openssl has command line options to do a handshake over stdin/stdout I believe.  Write a bash script to try the protocol or something.  If you don't know what I mean try opening a new question.